# How to combine few UVs to one using UDIM?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Good evening. I found out that ue5 supports only 4 UV layers for skeletal meshes, so I need to combine 3 UVs to one. I want to use UDIM for it. How can I do it? It should look like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set up the UDIM workspace:
In your image editor, set up the UDIM workspace. This typically involves setting up a grid or guides to help you properly place your UV maps.

Assign UDIM coordinates:
Using the UDIM naming convention, assign unique UDIM coordinates to each of your placed UV maps.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/workflows/udims.html

Comment: Hello. Well, I can't understand what to do at all. Link to workflow of udims is not helping, because its covering only texturing, but I don't need texture at all - I need to create UV UDIM.